# Accurate 3D Printing W/Sketchup

Tags: 3d-printing

I have 3D printers at my school, but unfortunately they are not super high quality. I want to try 3D printing a model I made on google sketchup, but I would like for it to be fairly accurate.

What measures can I take to prevent error in the model? I understand that I need to export the file as an STL; is there anything I can do to the model before hand to ensure accuracy?

What can I do to calibrate a 3D printer for best results?

Comment: What kind of 3D printer is it?

Comment: I wish I had more details on the specs. I will know more tomorrow

Comment: You might want to check out 123D (http://www.123dapp.com/).  It is a lightweight CAD package and set of tools for rapid prototyping (i.e. 3D printing) oriented for non-engineers.

Comment: When exporting to .stl a resolution can be set, it is effectively the number of triangles/subdivisions. Dunno about Sketchup though.

Comment: With 3D printing, there are many advantages this thing can do.
[3D Printing To Heal Skull Fractures](https://www.evolving-science.com/information-communication/3d-printing-heal-skull-fractures-00599)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found 3d printing with SketchUp:

- Use good geometry. Free Drawing should pretty much **never** be used. Make sure all of your arcs & angles are clean.
- You can **not** have unclosed areas. Some programs are very good about this. Sketchup is **not**. Lines that go no where should be removed, and all lines should be connected to the model.
- Pick a good ruby script for exporting as an STL. There are many free scripts available, and any of them should work if you do what is mentioned above.

Good Luck!